# How to refresh the tree when data is updated in backend

Tags: angularjs, treegrid

I am using tree-grid-directive (https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive) for my angularjs page.

The data is loaded from a REST backend.

Periodically the data will keep on changing (due to new additions or removals).

Now, i have routine that gets executed every 60 sec

```
 setInterval(function() {
     $scope.tree_data = getNewData($scope, $http);
 }, 60000);
```

Now, here it updates the list and the tree-grid refreshes.
But, the issues that i am facing are:
1. At a certain point of time, i may have clicked or expanded
   certain branches of the tree. Now, after the data update that is lost.
   How can i preserver that. How can i maintain the same expansion levels,
   and simultaneously display the new data also.

The whole update process is now creating a blinking effect... where the tree collapses to 0 and then i expand and after 60 secs again it collapses to 0.

So, is there a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`, because you need to run digest cycle manually after `setInteval`, and `$interval` does it after execution of callback function.

**Code**

```
$interval(function() {
     $scope.tree_data = getNewData($scope, $http);
 }, 60000);
```

Comment: I tried that also. The issue here is that the Tree grid is getting the new data, but the Tree collapses to minimal or root node. So, if i had expanded certain branches, then they all get collapsed

Comment: @JagannathdasRath it is because of ajax..it doesn't getting refreshed

Comment: Pankaj, can you please give me some more details... The tree is refreshed, but the expansion is lost....... the new data is visible if i expand it again

Comment: @Jagan that is correct behaviour, ng-repeat will rerendering that part of data, and that coming to its old test